# Pandas dataframe reformation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

guys I'm currently studying `pandas`.
I download a .csv file from UN data for studying.

http://data.un.org/Data.aspx?q=gdp&d=SNAAMA&f=grID%3a101%3bcurrID%3aUSD%3bpcFlag%3a1

However, this CSV file's form is not what I expected.
It looks like below.

```
Country or Area Year    Item    Value

0   Afghanistan 2016    Gross Domestic Product (GDP)    583.882867

1   Afghanistan 2015    Gross Domestic Product (GDP)    610.854517

2   Afghanistan 2014    Gross Domestic Product (GDP)    651.158326

3   Afghanistan 2013    Gross Domestic Product (GDP)    681.033974

4   Afghanistan 2012    Gross Domestic Product (GDP)    694.885886


...

9441    Zimbabwe    1974    Gross Domestic Product (GDP)    721.921573

9442    Zimbabwe    1973    Gross Domestic Product (GDP)    620.261471

9443    Zimbabwe    1972    Gross Domestic Product (GDP)    521.701845

9444    Zimbabwe    1971    Gross Domestic Product (GDP)    437.030171

9445    Zimbabwe    1970    Gross Domestic Product (GDP)    390.776187
```

I want to see each country's data in one row and years goes to columns name.

Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `unstack`

```
df.set_index(['Country or Area', 'Year'])['Value'].unstack()
```

Comment: will it work if number of years varies from country to country?

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar it will get unique year over all country and using np.nan as filling value by default